# How to replace one fragment with another on ListView item click android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment with simple ListView with images and text, and want to replace one fragment with another on ListView item click. How I can realize this?

Comment: use setonitemclicklistener on listview

Comment: What u have tried?

Comment: you can open new activity for listitemclick.its not good way to replace listview fragment with its onitemclicklistner fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(getFragmentContainerId(),fragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```